# Получить корректный boolean из базы данных

Tags: java, sql, spring-jdbc

Есть сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "deposits")
public class Deposit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "balance")
    private double balance;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    public Deposit() { }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

Перед записью в базу данных значение устанавливается TRUE (запись вносится корректно):

| id | balance | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | true |
| 2 | 0 | true |

Но при извлечении из БД все время извлекается только как FALSE.

(Метод извлечения из БД)

```
    public List<Deposit> getAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM deposits", new RowMapper<Deposit>() {
            @Override
            public Deposit mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Deposit deposit = new Deposit();
                deposit.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                deposit.setBalance(rs.getDouble(2));
                deposit.setActive(rs.getBoolean(3));
                System.out.println(deposit.isActive());
                return deposit;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Какого типа поле в БД?

Comment: Тренируюсь на SQLite

Comment: На сколько помню он не имеет реализации `bool`, попробуйте извлекать поле как `rs.getInt()`